# Are nested GraphQL queries with specific id values possible?

Tags: graphql

I've successfully built a GraphQL API which allows nested queries.  Using the generic examples of Countries & States, I can perform a query like this:

```html
    query{
      country(id:"Q291bnRyeTo0Nw==") {
        states {
          edges {
            node {
              id,
              name,
              area,
              population
            }
          }
        }
       }
     }
```

What I've discovered I can't seem to do is this:

```html
query{
      country(id:"Q291bnRyeTo0Nw==") {
        state(id:"U3RhdGU6MzM=") {
          edges {
            node {
              id,
              name,
              area,
              population
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Might there be a way with GraphQL to specify a specific parent and specific child in one query?

Robert

Update: For Daniel's benefit, here is my current GraphQL Query code:

```html
from .models import Country as CountryModel
from .models import State as StateModel

class Query(graphene.AbstractType):

    country = graphene.Field(Country, id=graphene.String())
    countries = graphene.List(Country)

    state = graphene.Field(State, id=graphene.String())
    states = graphene.List(State)

    def resolve_country(self, args, context, info):
        id = args.get('id')

        if id is not None:
            return CountryModel.objects.get(id=Schema.decode(id))
    
        return None

    def resolve_countries(self, args, context, info):
        return CountryModel.objects.all()

    def resolve_state(self, args, context, info):
        id = args.get('id')

        if id is not None:
            return StateModel.objects.get(id=Schema.decode(id))
    
        return None

    def resolve_states(self, args, context, info):
        return StateModel.objects.all()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with GraphQL, but is there a reason you have no closing parenthesis on the state line?

Comment: Typo.  Now corrected.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd need to define a resolver for both the `country` field on the Root Query and the `state` field on the Country type. Here's an example you can copy and paste into [Launchpad](https://launchpad.graphql.com/new) and see it in action.

The set up for something like Graphene would be a little different, but the idea is the same: the object returned by your `country` query is made available to the resolver for every field under the `state` type. You use the `id` argument passed to the `state` field to filter the data on that object (in this example, the returned object has a `states` property) and return the appropriate state.

```
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

const countries = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'bar',
    states: [
      {
        name: 'foo',
        id: 20
      }
    ]
  },
  { id: 2 },
];

const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    country(id: Int!): Country
  }
  type Country {
    id: Int
    state(id: Int!): State
  }
  type State {
   id: Int
   name: String
  }
`

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    country: (obj, args, context) => {
      return countries.find(country => country.id === args.id)
    },
  },
  Country: {
    state: (obj, args, context) => {
      return obj.states.find(state => state.id === args.id)
    },
  }
}

export const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
})
```

**Edit:** Assuming the object returned by `CountryModel.objects.get(id=Schema.decode(id))` includes a `states` attribute that is a list of states, you should be able to do something like:

```
class Country(graphene.ObjectType):
  state = graphene.Field(State,
                          id=graphene.String()
                          )
  # other fields
  def resolve_state(self, args, context, info):
    id = args.get('id')
    if id is not None:
        return list(filter(lambda x: x.id == id, self.states)
    return None
```

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your response.  I must confess, however, that I don't understand your code.  I'm guessing it's in Angular?

I have updated my original posting to include my current GraphQL Query code.

Comment: @Robert My Python's rusty but I edited the answer to include a Graphene example. You may need to modify how you fetch the data from the db to make sure the `country` object you give GraphQL to resolve includes the `states`